# CakePHP return invalid node

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying create a webapplication with CakePHP. I am newbie with that but i created a lot lines of code. Now i have to add ACL and now i have a big problem. My foreach loop with if statement call `$this->ACL->deny('Group', 'Alias in ARO table') or $this->ACL->allow('Group', 'Alias in ARO table')`. Everything is fine and automatic table acos_aros is modified great ... BUT !! i have one alias which generate something like that:

```
Warning (512): DbAcl::allow() - Invalid node [CORE\Cake\Model\Permission.php, line 182]
```

I have no idea why. It is 'Podopieczni' when i change to 'Podopieczn' or to 'Podopieczni1' then is working fine without any errors. Anybody can told me why alias 'Podopieczni' generate that error ?

**EDIT 1**
My bad. I have actually problem with ACO not Aro as said before. When i change alias in ACO table from Podopieczni to Podopieczni1 or something else is working. Alias Podopieczni is generate error.

Here is my code

```
public function pokaz(){    
        if ($this->request->is('post')){
            $acl['Aro'] = $this->Acl->Aro->find('list', array(
                'fields' => array('id', 'alias'),
                'conditions' => array(
                    'parent_id IS NULL' 
                )
            ));
            $acl['Aco'] = $this->Acl->Aco->find('list', array(
                'fields' => array('id', 'alias'),
                'conditions' => array(
                    'parent_id IS NULL' 
                )
            ));
            foreach($this->request->data['uprawnienia'] AS $pozycja => $uprawnienie){
                $t_aco = $acl['Aco'][split('-',$pozycja)[0]];
                $t_aro = $acl['Aro'][split('-',$pozycja)[1]];                                       
                if($uprawnienie){
                    //echo 'ALLOW: '.$t_aro.' => '.$t_aco.'<br>';
                    $this->Acl->Allow($t_aro, $t_aco);
                } else {
                    //echo 'DENY: '.$t_aro.' => '.$t_aco.'<br>';
                    $this->Acl->Deny($t_aro, $t_aco);
                }
            }
            //$this->redirect(array('controller'=>'admin', 'action' => 'pokaz'));
            //$this->render('/admin/pokaz');
            //exit;
        }
        $wynik = $this->Acl->Aco->find('all', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'parent_id is null'
            )
        ));         
        for($a=0; $a<count($wynik); $a++){
            $tmp = array();
            foreach($wynik[$a]['Aro'] AS $wiersz){
                $tmp[$wiersz['foreign_key']] = $wiersz;
            }
            $wynik[$a]['Aro'] = $tmp;
        }
        $this->set('wyniki', $wynik);
        $this->set('grupy', $this->requestAction('/admin/pobierzGrupy'));
    }
```

**SOLVED**
In the ACOS table I have two rows with this same alias. 
YOU ARE AWESOME *noslone*. VERY BIG THANKS FOR YOUR TIME AND PATIENCE :)))

Answer (score 0):

That alias does not exist in the `aros` or `acos` table.

You should create it first.

For ARO:

```
$aroData = array(
    'id' => NULL,
    'model' => 'Group', 
    'alias' => 'Podopieczni'
);
$this->Acl->Aro->save($aroData);
```

For ACO:

```
$acoData = array(
    'id' => NULL,
    'parent_id' => NULL,//or parent_id? 
    'alias' => 'Podopieczni'
);
$this->Acl->Aco->save($acoData);
```

You should read the [Documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html#simple-acl-controlled-application), it is explained pretty nice.

Comment: That alias is EXIST i see it in HeidiSQL and perfectly generate array with aliases. But he still returning error. When I change in aros table Podopieczni to something else is working great.

Comment: My bad, it should be `$this->Acl->deny('Group', 'alias in ACO table')`

Comment: Sorry man. I wrote bad, i still thinking about ACO table. Alias Podpoieczni generate some error.

Comment: In that case, the Aco alias does not exist. I have updated my answer.

Comment: I understand. But i explain you that record Podopieczni is exist in aco table and when i try execute ie: deny('Administratorzy', 'Podopieczni'); its return invalid node BUT if i change this same row from alias Podopieczni to alias Podopieczni1 its work perfectly.

Comment: I think your Aco table is corrupt. You should try to recover it.

Comment: I was truncated this table couple times. And stilk Podopieczni return invalid node.

Comment: Then you should doublecheck the creation(parent_id) of this alias in the acos table.

Comment: then told me why this same code fill acos table right but this one [bad word] row is want working

Comment: You should do some debugging. Try following: `$controller = $this->Acl->Aco->node('controller');` `$controllerAcos = $this->Acl->Aco->children($controller[0]['Aco']['id']);` `debug($controllerAcos)`

Comment: its return an array with all rows in acos table. and yes Podopieczni is exist